# Is there a formula for sin(a*b) like the addition formula?

Tags: trigonometry

This may be a dumb question but I wanted to know if there was a different way of writing sin(ab) similar to that of the addition formula or is it unnecessary?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Comment: those polynomials work when $a$ is a natural number